# Acumatica mass upload stock item images

Tags: acumatica

We have a list of stock items in Acumatica and now want to upload their pictures. 
Is there any way to mass upload images of stock items to Acumatica cloud platform?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for mass uploading of images to Stock or Non-stock items would be to use the built in Contract API, I have created the following sample code project that will use the in built "Default - 6.00.001" end point in version 6.1 or greater.

```
namespace MassInventoryItemImageUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //List of inventory Item CD's and associated file to upload.
            List<Tuple<string, string>> itemsToUpdate = new List<Tuple<string, string>>() { new Tuple<string, string>("InventoryItemCD", @"fileUrl") };

            Console.WriteLine("Updateing : " + itemsToUpdate.Count + " Inventory Items, press enter to begin");
            Console.ReadLine();

            AcumaticaProcessor processor = new AcumaticaProcessor();
            processor.Login();
            processor.UploadImages(itemsToUpdate);

            Console.WriteLine("Updates complete, press enter to exit program");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class AcumaticaProcessor
    {
        DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient();

        public void Login()
        {
            client.Login("username", "password", "Company", "branch", null);
        }

        public void UploadImages(List<Tuple<string, string>> updateItems)
        {
            //Foreach Inventory Item in the list we are going to upload a files
            foreach(Tuple<string,string> updateItem in updateItems)
            {
                UploadImage(updateItem);
            }
        }

        private void UploadImage(Tuple<string, string> updateItem)
        {
            try
            {
                //Finds the StockItem with the given InventoryCD
                StockItem itemToUpdate = new StockItem()
                {
                    InventoryID = new StringSearch() { Value = updateItem.Item1 }
                };
                itemToUpdate = client.Get(itemToUpdate) as StockItem;

                //Updates found StockItem to include associated files
                client.PutFiles(itemToUpdate, FileData(updateItem.Item2));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        //Creates Acumatica File object from filestream and return File[] for uplaod 
        private Acumatica.File[] FileData(string url)
        {
            byte[] fileData;
            using (FileStream file = System.IO.File.Open(url, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                fileData = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            }
            return new Acumatica.File[1] { new Acumatica.File() { Name = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1), Content = fileData } };
        } 
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Additional documentation : http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/02/contract-based-web-services-api.html